# How can I clown-proof an area?

Tags: terraria

During bloodmoons I like to use a bunny spawner setup to farm cash. I also have some other fancy stuff built near my bunny farm. However, during bloodmoons clowns spawn. Clowns are bad. Clowns throw bombs which blow stuff up. Clowns near my bunny spawner throw bombs which blow MY stuff up. How can I stop these clowns from blowing up my stuff?

[image]

Comment: Words alone cannot describe how awesome this title is.

Comment: There seems to be a lack of actual clowns in this screenshot.

Comment: @RavenDreamer I'll try to rectify that for you, but they seem to have replaced their funny with sneaky and explodey. I'll often find ridiculous amounts of damage just offscreen where I couldn't catch them in the act.

Comment: Clowns no longer blow up tiles (since 1.2).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The wiki suggests building your home out of Dungeon Bricks, which are immune to clown bombs. They're annoying to get, but they can't be bombed.

Of course, if you do this, you may run the risk of turning your home into a Dungeon biome, which presents its own problems. Make sure to build above sea level to avoid this possibility; the Dungeon is only considered to exist at -4 or below.

Comment: That's only when you're using dungeon brick *walls*. Just the brick themselves shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @RavenDreamer No, the bricks are in fact the problem. Using more than 250 causes the dungeon biome at a certain depth, but only if the player is standing in front of an unsafe wall. I think it starts at the point where natural dirt walls *stop*, so this shouldn't really ever be a problem since you can't place unsafe walls yourself anymore.

Comment: I don't think they're annoying to get, I always drill the poor old man's dungeon down while waiting for the night and challenging the Skeletron.